# How to decompose a matrix into a sum of circulant matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, circulant-matrices

I have a very particular matrix
$A = \alpha e_1 e_1^T$, where $\alpha$ is constant, means it has only one element in the diagonal that is different from zero.
Can this matrix be decomposed into a finite or infinite series of circulant matrices?

I have found this reference but did not quite understand it: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.14805.pdf

The goal is to make this matrix commute with a circulant matrix, even if I have to truncate the series approximately.

Comment: No. Any finite or infinite sum of circulant matrices is necessarily circulant.

Comment: @user1551, The guys from the article claim: We begin by showing that any nxn matrix can be decomposed into a sum of n circulant matrices with periodic relaxations on the unit circle.

Comment: From remark 1.1 and example 1.1 on p.2, it is clear that the authors mean that $A$ can be written in the form of $\sum_k\Lambda_kC^k$ where $C$ is a circulant matrix and each $\Lambda_k$ is a diagonal matrix. This strictly speaking is *not* a power series in $C$ (unless every $\Lambda_k$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix). In my opinion, the authors’ wording is very poor and misleading.